# Migrate AWS EIP across VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elastic-ip

I am creating a new VPC in our AWS account because the local CIDR has to change to support VPC cross region peering. I have public EIP's that I need to migrate over to the new VPC. Is it possible to migrate existing public EIP's from one VPC to another?

Comment: Yes. The EIPs are specific to the region not the VPC. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-eips.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the existing VPC and the proposed VPC are **within the same AWS region** (say `us-east-1`), you can disassociate the assigned EIP to an EC2 instance and associate it with another EC2 instance.

From the AWS Documentation [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html]:

> An Elastic IP address is for use in a specific region only.

While EIPs attached to running EC2 instances normally do not incur any charges, any unattached EIPs in an AWS account will incur charges. In your case, since you'll have an `unattached` EIP for a while before you re-associate it with your new AWS EC2 instance, you will incur charges for each hour of `unattached` EIP time. Pricing varies region to region and the most updated pricing can be found under the `Elastic IP Addresses` section at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

---

If the existing VPC and the proposed VPC are in **different AWS regions**, it is not currently possible to migrate EIPs between AWS regions.